# write a bash scipt that ssh's into multiple servers and runs a script there that starts an application but doesn't die when ssh disconnects

Tags: bash, ubuntu, ssh

This is what my script looks like. It kind of works because it does start the application on the remote servers and I can see the processes through top but when the script finishes the processes die. I need a way to leave the processes running on those remote servers indefinitely.
I can use this method to run commands on remote servers just fine. It's only when I try to run a script at the remote server that starts processes where I have the issue

```
#!/bin/bash
for HOST in $(cat servers.txt); do
   ssh user@$HOST nohup /opt/app.sh
done
#
```

Comment: Use `tmux` or `screen` to run the command on the remote server.

Answer (score 4):

Use `screen` on the remote hosts:

```
for host in $(cat hostlist.txt); do
   ssh user@${host} 'screen -dmS MyProcess /path/to/job.sh'
done
```

Comment: Tried utilizing screen as you mentioned but I get the same result. Processes start on the remote servers but when the local script above reaches "done" and finishes, the processes on the remote server die.

Comment: I would then look into the actual remote job; it sounds like it is executing and completing its task, and then terminating.  If this is the case, you'll need to call your task in a loop within the `screen` session; e. g. `screen -dmS MyJob "while sleep 60; do /path/to/job.sh; done"`.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using [pssh](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pssh) or [GNU parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) to run stuff on the remote computers.

Consider running on each remote machine your scripts using [`batch` or `at`](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/uat.htm).

So you could run `pssh -H host1 -H host2 batch -f remotescript.sh`

Perhaps a distributed build automation system like [icecream](https://github.com/icecc/icecream) could be useful too.